# CoreData: Inserting from array of dictionaries into SQLite database happens unsorted - set of Foreign Key therefore not possible

Tags: ios, json, swift, sqlite, core-data

I followed a tutorial on how to parse from a JSON file and preload a sqlite database according to this:
https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/parsing-json-response-and-save-it-in-coredata-step-by-step-fb58fc6ce16f

In this method the parsed data, which is an array of dictionaries, gets mapped:

```
private func saveInCoreDataWith(array: [[String: AnyObject]]) {
    _ = array.map{self.createPhotoEntityFrom(dictionary: $0)}
    do {
        try CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And in this method the mapped data gets inserted one by another into the database file:

```
private func createPhotoEntityFrom(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) -> NSManagedObject? {
    let context = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
    if let photoEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Photo", into: context) as? Photo {
        photoEntity.author = dictionary["author"] as? String
        photoEntity.tags = dictionary["tags"] as? String
        let mediaDictionary = dictionary["media"] as? [String: AnyObject]
        photoEntity.mediaURL = mediaDictionary?["m"] as? String
        return photoEntity
    }
    return nil
}
```

I noticed, that the data gets inserted in an unsorted manner and not according to the sorted way the array is prior of being inserted.
Normally this would not bother me when I would only have one entity. However in my project I have 3 entities and different relationships between them. Therefore I also need to set foreign keys into the tables. But this is not possible, since I don’t know which primary keys are going to be set initially when inserting the data into the tables.

Is there a way to tell SWIFT to insert the data sorted or at least according to the sorted array ? Or is there another way to determine the correct foreign keys when inserting into the table?

Comment: In CoreData you should not be worrying about Foreign Keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only order in Core Data is the order you tell it about. Ordering is not automatic. In most cases it's better to use a sort descriptor when fetching data, so that you can get fetch results sorted by a property of the entity (sorted by date, for example). If you need to force a specific order, your entity needs to have a property that indicates the order. Add an extra integer field called `sortOrder` and give it whatever values you like. Then have your sort descriptor sort using the `sortOrder` field.

Related, your question applies SQL concepts to Core Data in ways that don't make sense. Expecting an auto-incrementing index, for example. Wanting to use foreign keys for relationships as well. Core Data uses SQLite internally but it doesn't work like SQL, and thinking of it as SQL will lead you into bad design decisions like using foreign keys. If you really want SQLite, you can use it directly without Core Data. If you're going to use Core Data, you'll benefit from reading up on how it works instead of treating it like SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

CoreData insertion doesn't guarantee storing order of managed objects. To keep order of Your records You need to create custom field responsible for order and perform sorting while fetching.

Comment: What do you mean by I need to create custome field responsible for order?

Comment: Just add some field responsible for order and store it in DB.